# How to split a string multiple times in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

With a string like `"1 foo\n2 bar\n3 foobar"`, how do I split it into:

```
[["1", "foo"], ["2", "bar"] ["3", "foobar"]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work.

```
fn main() {
    let string: Vec<Vec<&str>> = "1 foo\n2 bar\n3 foobar".split('\n')
        .map(|x: &str| x.split(' ').collect())
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", string);
}
```

Comment: I'd use `lines()` instead of `split('\n')`